# asinh from fraction

Tags: calculus, fractions

If I have $$
\mathrm{asinh}\left(\frac{x}{2.8\cdot10^{-10}}\right) = 15
$$
How can I calculate $x$?
Should I use $\mathrm{asinh} \, x = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$
Or something else?

Comment: Why not apply $\sinh$ to both sides?

Comment: `(x/2.8*10^-10) = ASINH(15.0)` you mean that?

Comment: Let's say this, then. If you had the eqution $\operatorname{asinh}(y) = 15$, how would you solve it? Can you think of a single step that solves that equation? (Think about what $\operatorname{asinh}$ means. Not its formula, but its _meaning_ / definition.)

Comment: asinh(y) = ln(y +sqrt(y^2 + 1) = 15  then
ln(y +sqrt(y^2 + 1) = 15 and I can calculate y

Comment: I said _not_ to use the formula. What is the main reason for $\operatorname{asinh}$ to exist? What is its purpose?

Comment: If you want to copy and paste the wikipedia page its fine. I read it and this is only what I know. Still I dont know answer so I am asking.

Comment: Let me be a bit more direct, then: What do you know about the relationship between $\operatorname{asinh}(a)$ and $\sinh(a)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we're trying to solve:

$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{\frac{14}{5}\cdot10^{-10}}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\frac{14}{5}\cdot10^{-10}}\right)^2}\right)=15\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{7\sinh\left(15\right)}{25000000000}\tag1$$